Unable to pull newly created active OmniUiCard/Flexcard in to my local vs code
Whenever I try to pull the flex card using retrieve source from org/package.xml, I get the following error - 'Entity of type 'OmniUiCard' named 'Name of flexcard' cannot be found.

There is a omnistudio setting related to metadata deploy and retrieve in setup. We need to activate it.
